# vue packages version mismatch vue@1.0.28-csp

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm new to npm & vue and have followed instructions to install both.

When I run `vue create`, I get the follwing

```
Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@1.0.28-csp (C:\Users....vue.common.js)
- vue-template-complier@2.6.10 (c:\Users.....package.json)
```

How do I fix this?

I've seen others with a similar problem but not with the -csp file

My Vue version is 3.11.0.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue but I'm not sure how!

I uninstalled vue and then tried again:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
vue init webpack vueapp01 - I didn't do this last time, so maybe this is the answer!
```

Now when I do `vue create hello-world`, it works!

Thanks for your help @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Yarn equivalent worked for me  `yarn add @vue/cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vue-cli` version is `3.11.0`, not your `vue` version. You have globally installed version of `vue` at `1.0.28-csp`. What you should do is:

```
npm update -g vue
```

or

```
yarn global update vue
```

which should bring it in line with the template compiler.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help.....I've fixed the problem now...see my answer below